# Как расставить узлы произвольного дерева?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, графы

Есть произвольное дерево, `узлы-братья` удалены друг от друга на динамически задаваемое значение (в данном случаи 20), так же как и `узлы-соседи` (в данном случаи 40). В тот момент, когда самая левая ветвь формируется, вызывается метод `расстоновка_узлов` в который передается `самый верхний-левый` и `самый верхний-правый` и `разница на которую увеличился промежуток между ними` (в данном случаи 20).
Вот что происходит в методе `расстоновка_узлов` -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. в цикле проходим от верхний-левой до верхней-правой и считаем промежутки (в данном случаи это шесть пустых клеточек, которые как говорил ранее по 20, то есть сумма 120);
2. делю сумму полученную на предыдущем шаге на кол-во узлов плюс один (120 / 3 = 40);
3. проверяю на сколько текущий узел (я начинаю с лева на право и по этому текущий узел это тот у которого два ребенка) удален от левого `узла-брата` (в данном случаи это 80).
4. теперь я вычитаю из 80 - 40 = 40, это значение расстояние на которое я смещу текущую ноду чтобы оказаться в нужном месте.
5. если это значение (40) больше чем то на которое увеличилось расстояние между двумя крайними нодами, то это значение становится меньшим. То есть рассчитал что 40, но оно больше позволенного и по этому значение меняется на 20.
6. перемещаю ноду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повторяю шесть предыдущих шагов для следующей ноды -
1. получаю 60
2. 60 / 2 = 30
3. 40
4. 30
5. 10
6. ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите как я усреднил? Сначала выяснил что сдвинуть нужно на сорок, но так как на сорок сдвинуть я не могу (нарушится правило для нижних детей, они будут ближе чем на сорок), я сдвигаю на максиму возможное, это двадцать. А потом я сдвигаю уже на десять.
Для примера, если бы у первой обрабатываемой ноды не было детей, то картина была бы следующей -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На тот случай, если у меня сначала идет узел который можно сдвинуть на "сколько-то" (без детей), а после тот который уже нельзя сдвинуть на "сколько-то", то второй я снова сдвигаю на максимум, но при этом выполняю алгоритм с самого начала (точнее с самой последней удачной точки), но на время подменяю `самый верхний-правый` `текущим`.

Я бы показал код, но я не хочу чтобы Вы смотрели его недочеты, а лишь хочу чтобы Вы поняли смысл.

Вот. Но дальше я столкнулся с следующей проблемой, да и возможно это только одна из ...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Входные данные те же, но все ломается. Алгоритма, как я хотел, не получилось, да и придумать я не могу.
Ниже конечный результат - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что есть у нод
indent - значение на которое текущая нода удалена от предыдущей |*|->|*|
leftOffset - это значение на которое я смещаю влево. В самом начале оно ноль
rightOffset = это то значение на которое смещаю вправо. И тоже по дефолту ноль.

Вот. Сами ноды, как обычные ноды, ссыдка на парента, в котором они хранятся в индексированном массиве. Есть методы для получения ноды по индексу и получение самого индекса.

Comment: Вы описали какой-то довольно сложный алгоритм, который... не работает. Только вот какого результата вы ожидаете не написали. Ну, то есть, если пару раз перечитать и поискать 10 отличий у картинок можно примерно догадаться, что это фрагмент дерева, и что надо компактно и притом равномерно расположить ноды... Хватило бы двух картинок что в начале, что в итоге.

Comment: Порядок детей у ноды в списке при размещении статический или динамический? Т.е. можно ли переставить родителя самой нижней ноды на последней картинке вправо? И ещё, на второй картинке ошибка, верхний уровень находится на расстояниях, меньших 40, т.е. самое правое дерево надо двигать вправо на 20, тогда будет влезать.

Comment: @Vesper: порядок детей статический, то есть он не изменяется. Когда мне нужно сделать усреднение, то часть дерева, которая попала в фокус такая как на картинке. Дерево собирается в обратном порядке, с права на лева. Двигать можно только те родительские  узлы, которые находятся между самыми крайними. Родительские узлы которые можно двигать всегда являются братьями, то есть между ними динамически задаваемое расстояние (в данном случаи 20). И ошибок нигде нет.

Comment: О_о А зачем так ограничиваться? А если места просто нет между крайними, чтобы правильно разместить средние узлы? По мне, правильно будет собирать вначале каждое поддерево, а потом их расставлять так, чтобы на всех уровнях поддеревья не мешались друг другу по threshold.

Comment: @Yura Ivano: результат это третья картинка. Если мое описание алгоритма путает, то можно смотреть на картинке - первая картинка что есть в начале, вторая что есть после первой итерации, третья результат после второй итерации - конечный результат. Четвертая картинка показывает отношение брат-сосед по отношению к третьей картинке. Самая последняя картинка показывает один из вариантов, который поломал мой алгоритм. Его конечным результатом будет сдвиг на десять влево.

Comment: @Vesper: я не понимаю о чем Вы... Вы говорите что на втором рисунке где-то что-то меньше сорока. Но нет, сорок это две клеточки и там нет неправильно. И про ограничение не понял так как случай максимально приближен к идеалу.

Comment: И если Вам мое описание нерабочего алгоритма мешает, то скажите я только картинки оставлю.

Comment: @shatal мешает то, что нет никакого описания что же должно быть результатом алгоритма. строгих требований. "расстояния между узлами должно соответствовать следующим требованиям: ...". что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: @PashaPash: если Вы хотите чтобы я описал требования, по пунктам, то это просто невозможно. Вы не можете понять по рисункам, а по описанию требований Вы точно не поймете, так как они будут в разы больше чем весь вопрос. Первая картинка что было в начале, третья что нужно получить.  И тоже самое с пятой и шестой.

Comment: @shatal ок, т.е. вы хотите что-бы кто-то исправил ваш алгоритм (который явно неправильный, и который судя по всему состоит из набора частных решений-костылей для проблем, которые вылезли в процессе). По трем картинкам. При количестве неизвестных требований "больше чем весь вопрос". Ок, удачи вам.

Comment: @PashaPash:Вы знаете, я рассчитываю на помощь людей, которые по большей части математики и такие задачи им понятны и они не смогут выдать результат, как Вы сказали набор костылей, который бы Вы смогли предложить после трех недель размышлений и назвали - алгоритмом.  Я уже предложил удалить все свои описания, чтобы они не отвлекали. И я не прошу помощи в доработки моего способа, так как он нерабочий,я прошу нового решения. И да, удача,пусть и ироничная,в током сложном вопросе мне не помешает. Вы бы его все равно не смогли решить даже за пол века, по этому и иронию из Ваших уст меня не задевает.

Comment: " Его конечным результатом будет сдвиг на десять влево." - а я не вижу, где алгоритм поломан. Последний уровень не дает сдвинуть правое поддерево ещё дальше влево, левое поддерево - база, как стоит, так и стоит, а среднее стоит посередине между разрешенными положениями +60 и +80 от левого.

Comment: @PashaPash Алгоритм-то, похоже, правильный, работает как надо, а проблема с интерпретацией его результатов. И такое бывает. Что интересно, я затеял его улучшить, а потом остановился и обнаружил, что пишу то же самое, что описано в вопросе, только другими словами.

Comment: @Vesper Я не пытаюсь сказать что алгоритм "неправильный". Просто судя по картинке там требования "не ближе чем 20/40" и "как можно равномернее" (что практически дает решение - "листья впритык, остальные ноды - как можно ближе к средней плотности на уровне, в пределах ширины детей". Это то, что можно вывести по картинке. Если там еще есть требования - я не понимаю почему их нельзя изложить.

Comment: @shatal "по большей части математики" всегда пытаются формализовать требования. Потом написать тесты для проверки, что требования выполняются. А потом написать код. Вы просите нового решения на основании трех картинок. Я более чем уверен, что описание формальных требований с трех картинок можно уместить в 10 строк. И что вам стоит это сделать хотя бы для того, чтобы не гадать над правильностью своего же решения.

Comment: @PashaPash Да, требования именно такие, при этом более глубокий анализ (шестая картинка, в частности) показал, что алгоритм их выполняет как положено. И я так понял, что больше требований как раз нет.

Comment: @Vesper "по описанию требований Вы точно не поймете, так как они будут в разы больше чем весь вопрос" - судя по всему есть, и много.

Comment: @Vesper кстати, ваше решение этим требованиям не соответствует - там явно неравномерная раскладка.

Comment: @PashaPash Я вначале думал, что проблема в расстановке, потом она была локализована в пост-расстановочной фазе, а потом я стал обновлять ответ и выяснил, что пишу в точности то, что описано автором в методе `расстоновка_узлов` (те шесть шагов с конкретизацией после третьей картинки). Ну и не стал обновлять ответ.

Comment: @Vesper проблема не в расстановке. Проблема в отсутствии требований (ну или в том, что они никак не формализованы). Потому что если требования сводятся к тому, что я написал выше - то решение выводится прямо из них - высчитать количество нод на каждом уровне, применить ограничение "не шире". Пара проходов по дереву и готово. А если требования не формализованы - то любая попытка решить задачу - это трата времени.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, нужно расставлять узлы уже по факту, а не извращаться с двиганием в каких-то рамках. Есть обе константы, "братья" и "соседи", причем "соседи" определяет, насколько должны отстоять друг от друга соседние поддеревья на уровнях ниже первого, а "братья" - на первом. Тогда задачу нужно решать снизу вверх: для каждого поддерева вначале выстраиваем каждое из собственных поддеревьев, после чего выстраиваем текущее подерево, вычисляя для каждого следующего поддерева минимальное смещение относительно нуля, при котором на каждом уровне это поддерево не будет мешать уже установленным поддеревьям. В итоге каждое подерево будет иметь параметр "занятый диапазон" на каждом уровне, где у него есть хоть один лист, по нему и будет идти сравнение при размещении текущего поддерева на верхнем уровне.

Т.е. алгоритм выглядит так:

```
BuiltTree buildTree(Tree tree) {
    BuiltTree[] siblings;
    foreach (subTree in tree.subTrees) siblings.push(buildTree(subTree));
    BuiltTree result=new BuiltTree(); // пустое
    foreach (sibling in siblings) {
        int minRightPos=0;
        for (i=0;i<sibling.depth;i++) {
            if (result.depth<1+i) break; // у result на текущем уровне нет поддеревьев
            if (i==0) minRightPos=max(minRightPos,BRATYA-sibling.left[i]+result.right[i+1])
            else minRightPos=max(minRightPos,SOSEDI-sibling.left[i]+result.right[i+1]);
            // считаем, как далеко нужно отставить sibling от собранного поддерева
        }
        result.AddSiblingAtOffset(sibling,minRightPos); // добавляем его справа
    }
    result.positionRoot(tree.node,minRightPos/2); // ставим корень в середину из голов поддеревьев
    return result;
}
```

`right` заполняется следующим образом: Если добавляемое поддерево на i-m уровне не имеет заполненного right, то на i+1-m уровне right не изменяется, если же имеет, то right становится равным присланному offset плюс имеющийся right. `left` заполняется схожим образом, но заполняется, только если на данном уровне ещё не заполнен - так как новые поддеревья добавляюстя справа, первое поддерево с заданной глубиной установит left этому поддереву. При выполнении `positionRoot()` весь массив right и left уменьшается на position, после чего в начало массивов добавляется 0.

Попытаюсь описать разворачивание алгоритма. Для описания дерева буду использовать списки Лиспа, числа - листы, списки - поддеревья. Пример: `((1) (2 3 4 5))` соответствует такому дереву:

```
 root
 |
 *-----*
 |  +-+^+-+
 1  2 3 4 5
```

Исходное дерево: `(((1) 2) (((3))) ((4 5 6) ((7 8 9) (10))))`. Поддеревья из одного листа не рассматриваю, ибо незачем. Поддерево `((1) 2)` имеет значение: `left=[0,-10,-10]; right=[0,10,-10]` и следующий вид:

```
  *
 +^+
 * 2
 |
 1
```

Звездочки обозначают вершины поддеревьев, так как в списках нет элемента "корень" . Поддерево `(((3)))` имеет тривиальный вид и значение массивов `left=[0,0,0,0]; right=[0,0,0,0]`. Поддерево `((7 8 9) (10))` имеет значение массивов `left=[0,-30,-50]; right=[0,30,30]` и выглядит так:

```
     *
  +--^--+
  *     *
+-+-+   |
7 8 9   10
```

Из-за того, что поддерево (7 8 9) получило right[1] как 20, а смещение "соседи" 40, второе поддерево было помещено по смещению 60 (0+40+20), а positionRoot был вызван со смещением 30 (=60/2), в итоге левое поддерево провалилось в минус относительно общего кроня на -50. Сборка поддерева 4-10 будет выглядеть так:

```
      *
  +---^----+
  *        *
+-+-+   +--^--+
4 5 6   *     *
      +-+-+   |
      7 8 9   10
```

Ограничителем положения правого поддерева здесь выступает второй слой, где у (4 5 6) right[1]=20, а left[1] у поддерева -30, итого общее смещение будет 90. На нижнем уровне у левого поддерева нет элементов, поэтому его пропускаем. В итоге positionRoot будет вызван с положением 55, и общий массив выглядит как `left=[0,-55,-75,5]; right=[0,55,85,85]`. После чего сборка из трех поддеревьев будет выстроена так: первое ставится по смещению 0, второе `(((3)))` по смещению 50, и большое третье по смещению 50+40+(-75) = 165, и голова будет смещена на 87.5. Итого получится такая картина:

```
          *
 +----+---^-------+
 *    *           *
+^+   |       +---^----+
* 2   *       *        *
|     |     +-+-+   +--^--+
1     *     4 5 6   *     *
      |           +-+-+   |
      3           7 8 9   10
```

Из-за округлений в третьем ряду между звездочкой и 4 четыре пробела вместо трех (я считал один символ = 10 точек, но я считал элементы не имеющими ширины, таким образом, вместо 20 и 40 в вопросе нужно ставить константы 40 и 60).

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Апдейт: Технически можно после распределения поддеревьев таким образом искать те поддеревья, которые можно подвинуть внутри отображения, не мешая остальным, и если проблема именно тут, то её на самом деле нет, так как после расстановки всех поддеревьев получен наиболее компактный вариант размещения всего дерева в ширину, и если какие-то поддеревья можно двигать, т.е. у них появляется диапазон разрешенных позиций, вы можете использовать имеющийся у вас алгоритм. А то, что дерево в итоге очень громоздкое по ширине, это не является проблемой как таковой.

Comment: Вы меня простите за мои поспешные выводы (я до конца ещё не смог вникнуть в Ваш ответ), но мне не нужно формировать дерево и расставлять дерево, оно у меня уже сформировано и расставлено. На рисунке у меня не три дерева, а одна ветвь, чилды которой нужно усреднить.

Comment: Тогда у вас нет проблем здесь. Среднее поддерево находится посередине из возможных для него положений.

Comment: И вот в самом последнем абзаце Вы правильно сказали о "родительских узлах которые некому не мешают". У меня именно тот случай, когда поддеревья оказываются в замкнутом пространстве, замкнутые детьми своих братьев, но их можно сдвигать. Именно этот момент у меня и не получается.

Comment: Вы знаете, я два дня не могу это сделать, но только после Ваших слов, что все нормально я понял, что показываемый мной случай не является ошибкой. Но ошибка все-таки есть  и я сейчас сам её попробую решить, но если не получится, то я перепишу весь вопрос..

Comment: Лучше задайте ещё один, поскольку хотя общая задача та же, конкретная решаемая проблема наверняка окажется отличной от той, что описана здесь.